# Django Celery Rabbitmq: Connection reset by peer

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am new with this celery, rabbitmq, and django.

im very confused with this error, dont know how to track the error and read the error log.

i used:
celery 4.1.0
rabbitmq 3.7.15
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:64]

[this picture of when i run celery -A tasks worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haDoe.png)

anyone please help me, how to solve this. not really know how to fix this.
thank, and pardon my english.